# Function setGradient

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a code which changes the background color depending on the colors chosen by the user in a gradient way
the setGradient function isn't working or isn't called I don't know where is the mistake i revised the code many time but i couldn't figure out the problem.. plz help me :)
thank u in advance ^^

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gradient Background</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
body{
    font-family:'Lucida Console';
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(65,55,99,0.5);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2em;
    top: 15%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black , white);
}

h1{
    font-family:'Lucida Console';
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(25,140,9,0.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2em;

}
</style>
<script>
    var color1 = document.getElementsByClassName("color1");
    var color2 = document.getElementsByClassName("color2");
    var body = document.getElementById("gradient");

function setGradient() {
    body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, " + color1.value + 
    ", " + color2.value + ")" ;
 } 

// color1.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
// color2.addEventListener("input", setGradient);

</script>
</head>
<body id="gradient">
<h1>Background Generator</h1>
<input oninput="setGradient()" class="color1" type="color" name="color1" 
value="#000000">
<input oninput="setGradient()" class="color2" type="color" name="color2" 
value="#ffffff">
<h2>Current CSS Background</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I drop this into a Pen, I get a couple errors.

The first one is 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined`
I receive this error because the script is at the head of the document, and it is trying to set event listeners on elements that do not exist.

So the first answer is: **Move the script to the bottom of the body.**

But that still doesn't fix it - and that's because you're using [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) incorrectly. But you're very close. This function returns HTMLCollection - so you're trying to add the event listener to a group of objects (even if that group is only one object. To fix this, you want to append [0] to get the first object from the collection returned by that call.

So your code should read:

```
    var color1 = document.getElementsByClassName("color1")[0];
    var color2 = document.getElementsByClassName("color2")[0];
```